# How to compute mean vector and covariance matrix of equal distributions?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, normal-distribution, self-study

This question is an extended version of [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18294/what-does-equal-a-priori-class-probabilities-mean).

As you can see here, two distributions are equal, I need to compute the parameters a,b,c,d and e. Could you show me a way to do that?

---

Assume a two-class problem with equal a priori class probabilities and Gaussian class-conditional densities as follows:

$$p(x\mid w_1) = {\cal N}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} a & c \\ c & b \end{bmatrix}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad p(x\mid w_2) = 
{\cal N}\left(\begin{bmatrix} d \\ e \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right)$$

where $ab-c^2=1$.

Comment: _Which_ distributions do you say are equal?  $p(x\mid w_1)$ equals $p(x\mid w_2)$ exactly when $a = b = 1$ and $c = d = e = 0$.  There must be something else that you have been told but are not revealing to us.

Comment: @DilipSarwate $p(x\mid w_1)$ and $p(x\mid w_2)$ are equal. I thought the same way but $ab-c^2=1$ equation makes me start thinking that i am wrong.

Comment: You really should post the entire question in full. Perhaps, you are on the wrong track as your question does not make much sense. Why do you say: "As you can see, two distributions are equal.."? I see no such thing and it is not at all obvious why you would make a statement like that.

Comment: @varty i made a typo at the question. I am going to fix that and write down all the question.

Comment: Hint: Write the _actual_ density functions that you are expressing as by $p(x\mid w_1)$ and $p(x\mid w_2)$. Remember that each is a joint density function of two random variables, and so both joint densities will be functions of two real variables, say $x_1$ and $x_2$. If you do this correctly, you will have written things that have a common factor $1/2\pi$ and contain exponential functions whose arguments include _quadratic_ expressions in $x_1$ and $x_2$. The boundary of the decision region is the set of points $(x_1,x_2)$ where the two densities that you have written are equal in value.

Comment: This question was undeleted and rolled back to the version actually answered.  A [related question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18316/decision-boundaries-and-gaussian-density-functions), which was originally a duplicate, no longer is the same and so has also been reopened.

Comment: @whuber There is a [third question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18316/6633) on the same problem which I think is what the OP really wanted to know for his homework assignment 11 months ago. Perhaps a link to that question could be included here too.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: The answer below responded to the original version of the OP's question, which was quite different in nature and less specific than the current version.

---

> $p(x∣w_1)$ and $p(x∣w2)$ are equal.

OK, this is going to take a lot longer to answer.

In some statistical applications, a statistician (or a machine, since
you included machine learning as a tag) needs to decide which of two
hypotheses is true:  $H_1 \colon w = w_1$ and $H_2 \colon w = w_2$.
It is known that $$P(w = w_1) = P(w = w_2) = \frac{1}{2}.$$
*This* is what the *equal a priori probabilities* that you keep referring 
to means.

Here is a simple method:  Always *decide* that $w = w_1$, and so hypothesis
$H_1$ is always the true hypothesis.  When *in fact* $H_1$ is true, your
decision is
perfectly correct; when *in fact* $H_2$ is true your decision is
perfectly wrong, and
thus you have a $50\%$ chance of making an error.  More sophisticated methods
use a coin toss or a call to a random number generator to decide, but unfortunately still have a $50\%$ chance of making an an error; the same
as the simpler mulish insistence that $H_1$ is always true.

To get better performance, i.e., smaller error probability), the 
statistician might observe a random variable whose distribution depends
on the value of $w$.  If $w = w_1$, the distribution is $p(x\mid w_1)$;
if $w = w_2$, the distribution is $p(x\mid w_2)$.  For example, if
$w = w_1$, $x$ is a normal random variable with mean $100$ and variance $1$,
while if $w = w_2$, $x$ is a standard normal random variable with mean $0$ and 
variance $1$.  So if the statistician observes that $x$ has value $101.2$,
it is highly likely that $w = w_1$ and thus very likely that
$H_1$ is true because a standard
normal random variable is quite unlikely to have large value.  On the other
hand, if $x$ has small value (say between $-4$ and $+4$), then it is quite
likely that $H_2$ is true and $w = w_2$.  But notice that all this depends
critically on the distributions $p(x\mid w_1)$ and $p(x\mid w_2)$ being
*different*.  If the distributions are the same, then observing $x$ is of 
no help in deciding between $H_1$ and $H_2$.  Thus when you claim that

> $p(x∣w_1)$ and $p(x∣w_2)$ are equal

you are effectively insisting that observing $x$ is useless as 
far as deciding between $H_1$ and $H_2$ is concerned.

So, how are these distributions known in the first place?  The client might provide
them to the statistician based on the knowledge of how the client's
apparatus works.  Your professor, like Professor Indiana Jones in the
movie *Raiders of the Lost Ark*, might
be making them up as he goes along  (Remember that $99\frac{44}{100}\%$
of all statistics are made up!).  In the context of machine 
learning, there may be *training samples* provided:  Here are
$200$ observations of $x$ when $H_1$ is true, and here are
$200$ more when $H_2$ is true.  (In your particular problem,
$x$ is a *bivariate* normal random variable with independent
(standard normal) components when $H_1$ is true and correlated 
normal components when
$H_2$ is true, and so each sample would be a a pair of numbers).
The machine *estimates*
$p(x\mid w_1)$ from the first set of observations
and $p(x\mid w_2)$ from the second set, and uses these
estimates when making decisions when the real work comes
along.

In summary, your claim that $p(x\mid w_1) = p(x\mid w_2)$
means that $x$ is totally useless in distinguishing the two
cases.  For your *particular* distribution, equality holds
(if you nevertheless contiunue to insist on equality)
exactly when $a=b=1$ and $c=d=e=0$ (in which case $ab-c^2 = 1$
as desired).  There is no way of *solving* for $a,b,c,d,e$,
or saying  what values of $a,b,c,d,e$ make sense in your 
problem based on the information that you have provided.
You need to be given these by your professor,
or you need to be given training data so that you can *estimate*
these parameters, or you should emulate Professor Jones
and make up some numbers (subject to the constraints that $ab - c^2 = 1$
and $a, b > 0$) and solve the problem using these.

Comment: @onatm You have edited and changed the problem statement while I was writing the above answer, and some of my comments are no longer applicable.

Comment: thank you for your great answer, it is really informative even i gave you a poor explanation about my problem.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question (at least very directly), but it's very possible that this is due to the edit to the question that happened around the same time. The real question appears to be how to find the Bayes optimal decision boundary between the two classes.

Comment: @cardinal I was responding to the original question: "Two distributions are equal, I need to compute the parameters a,b,c,d and e. Could you show me a way to do that?" which seemed to show that the OP did not even understand the basic notion that the two distributions needed to be different if $x$ was going to be of any help in distinguishing between the two classes.  He continued to insist that the two distributions were identical.  If you feel that my answer is inappropriate, please feel free to edit it or even delete it entirely.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Oh, dear. No, I would certainly never "delete" the content of another user's post! Rather, the effort you put into trying to understand the OP's question (and respond to it!) in its original (rather muddled) form is quite Herculean. Rather, I will edit to add a disclaimer at the top so that it isn't inadvertently downvoted!