# Find corresponding linear discriminant function in a two-class, three-dimensional classification

Tags: normal-distribution, bayes

I am new to Patter Recognition and I am kind of stuck at a homework assignment. Any help regarding the issue will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

**In a two-class, three-dimensional classification problem, the feature vectors in
each class are normally distributed with covariance matrix:**

|0.3 0.1 0.1 |
|0.1 0.3 0.1 | = ∑ 
|0.1 0.1 0.3 |

**The respective mean vectors are [0, 0, 0]t and [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]t. 

Derive the
corresponding linear discriminant functions and the equation describing the
decision surface.**

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any Bayesian component to what you are describing. Write down the multivariate normal densities $f_0(x,y,z)$ and $f_1(x,y,z)$ under the hypotheses $H_0: \mu = (0,0,0)$ and $H_1: \mu = (0.5,0.5,0.5)$. The decision
surface is the set of all $(x,y,z)$ for which $f_0(x,y,z) = f_1(x,y,z)$. You
will find that it helps to equate $\ln f_0(x,y,z)$ and $\ln f_1(x,y,z)$ and
proceed from there, and the answer might surprise you a little. Don't compute
the *numerical values* of entries of the matrix inverse of $\Sigma$ 
before you actually need numerical values: that is, simply assume that the 
inverse is a symmetric matrix $A = [a_{i,j}]$ and write the densities in 
terms of *symbols* $a_{i,j}$ rather than *numbers* such as $0.25$.

A two-dimensional version of this question but with $f_0$ and $f_1$ having
different covariance matrices (which complicates matters a lot)
is answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/40611/6633).